# nginx on mac - dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib

Tags: macos, nginx

I have installed nginx on mac using source. Commands used are as below.

```
cd pcre-8.40

/configure --prefix=/Users/nginx_folder/

make && make install && make clean

cd ..

cd ngnix-1.10.3

/configure --prefix=/Users/nginx_folder/ --with-pcre=../pcre-8.40 --with-http_ssl_module

make && make install && make clean
```

After installing when i ran nginx it is throwing below error.

```
Error:
-----------
dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/nginx_folder/nginx/sbin/./nginx
  Reason: no suitable image found.
```

Can any one help me resolving this error?

Comment: why are you not using brew to install nginx?

Comment: @Tarun - machine does not have access to internet as it is secured. So I have used source to install the software.

Comment: See if this helps http://hanoian.com/content/index.php/23-compile-nginx-with-openssl-on-mac-os-x-64-bit